# How to Generate New Key for Redux State Item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having a little trouble figuring out what the best practice may be for adding new items to my React/Redux state with new keys.

Given the state:

```
const initialState = {
  "routines": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Routine 1",
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Routine 2",
    }
  }
}
```

Let's say I want to add a new item into this state. Where should I put the logic for coming up with the new ID?

1. Should that be a property of the form whose submittal triggers the ADD_ROUTINE action?
2. Should the logic for generating the new id be in the reducer?

Here is my best attempt, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

```
import { ADD_ROUTINE } from '../actions/routineActions'

function routineReducer(state={}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ROUTINE:
      newState = {...state}
      number_of_keys = Object.keys(newState).length
      new_id = number_of_keys + 1
      return {
        ...state,
        new_id: {
          id: new_id,
          name: action.name,
          days: []
        }
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default routineReducer
```

Comment: This looks fine to me. The reducer is meant to calculate the new state, and you can use the old state in your calculations. FYI you have a small bug in your reducer. Try `[new_id]: {` instead of `new_id: {`

Comment: Basing ID on length (i.e the number of routines in the previous state) works as long as you do not delete routines. It might be a better idea to fetch the last routine in the previous state and increment its ID by 1.
I would also, personally, change the structure of your "routines" object to an array, but that's another discussion.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid to generate RFC-compliant *unique* IDs

Comment: @Jaxx thanks! i'll take a look at that package! Out of curiosity, what advantages would be available having routines as an array vs an object.

Comment: @BenLorantfy Thanks for point that out, i'll fix it :)

Comment: @JordanCoil First of all, you have redundant data, since you're using the same value of "id" twice for every object, so you could easily remove one, and since you want every routine object to be "self-contained" (by that I mean a coherent entity on its own), you would want to keep the "id" that is inside the routine object. Once you get rid of the outside "id", you do not need an object structure anymore, a simple array to hold all routine objects is sufficient, and a lot easier to manipulate (think of all the Array methods like map, filter, reduce, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comments and suggestions about a change of structure, here is how I would write your reducer:

```js
import { ADD_ROUTINE } from '../actions/routineActions'

// important: this assumes changing the structure
// of the initial state to the following:
// routines = [
//   { id: 1, name: 'routine 1' },
//   { id: 2, name: 'routine 2' },
// ]

function routineReducer(state=[], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ROUTINE:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: state[state.length - 1].id + 1,
          name: action.payload,
        }
      ]
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default routineReducer
```

Even with this rewrite, I still feel generating RFC-compliant UUIDs using the [uuid npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) would be a cleaner solution (regardless of how you structure your state, array or object).

Comment: We should use state.length!==0 ? state[state.length - 1].id + 1: 1 because in case length == 0 we get error